# Route not defined - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've created a button that will reset all the values ​​inside the checkboxes. This happens thanks to a method that performs an update thanks to an ID.

View:

```
<div>
        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT','route' => ['checklists.updateRichiesta', $richiesta->id]]) !!}
        <button type="submit" onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" class="#">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

ChecklistController:

```
public function updateRichiesta(Request $request, $id)
{
    \App\Checklist::where('richiesta_id', $id)->update(['isCheck' => 'false']);
    \App\Richiesta::where('id', $id)->update(['stato' => 1]);
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Route.php

```
Route::resource('checklists', 'ChecklistController');
```

Error:

```
Route [checklists.updateRichiesta] not defined.
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `resource` route, the name of update route is `update`. So, change the route name to:

```
'route' => ['checklists.update', ...
```

And rename controller method to `update`:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Can i pass another data from form?$id and $type.
I receive an error like this, Missing argument 3.
Some advice?

Comment: @CarmineRub no, you can't do that with `resource`. But you can pass type with input hidden element `<input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{ $type }}">` and get it in controller with `$request->type`

Answer (score 0):

Either edit your form opening tag like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT','route' => ['checklists.update', $richiesta->id]]) !!}
```

or add updateRichiesta method to your controller

Answer (score 0):

As it is a resource you must used the resource syntax to defined routes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

In this case you would call the route by:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT','route' => ['checklists.update', $richiesta->id]]) !!}
```